# Prove the multiplication of order axioms with negative

Tags: analysis

Can anybody prove the multiplication order axiom with a negative number? I mean, prove that

if $a<b$ and $c<0$ then $ac>bc$ and also prove that $1>0$

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition you have for $a > b$ or $a < b$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the meaning of $a < b$, and that $-c$ must be a member of $\mathbb{N}$ (or if you're working with reals, $\mathbb{R}^+$).

(Is this homework? If so, what have you done so far?)